# Input.GetMouseButtonUp not working as expected in Unity

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, mouse

I have a 2D Unity game with numerous agents that can be selected when they are clicked on. When this happens they become the player (the player's agent variable is replaced with them and the agent becomes the player's parent). I am trying to implement a system where you drag their destination over another agent to "Target" them.

To do this I am actually targeting from within the target's My class (a class that holds references to all the player's components and variables) so I am putting the agent into a function that is operated by the player's current agent. This seems to work in theory, but in Unity it is only allowing me to target the first agent in the hierarchy, and none of the others. But all the agents are identical instances of the agent prefab, generated at the start of the game.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Agent : Grammar {
    public Physical physical;
    public Agent agent;

    void Update() {

        float distanceFromMouse = the.Distance(this.transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {

            if (distanceFromMouse < 1f) {
                the.player.agent = this;
                the.player.transform.parent = this.transform;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {

            if (distanceFromMouse < 1f) {
                if (the.player.agent != this && the.player.agent is Agent) {
                    the.player.agent.Target (agent);
                }
            }

            the.player.agent = null;
        }

        if (the.player.agent == agent)
            physical.goal = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        else if (physical.hasTarget)
            physical.goal = physical.target.transform.position;
    }
}

public void Target (My target) {

    my.physical.target = target;
    my.physical.hasTarget = true;

    foreach (My other in the.agents.GetComponentsInChildren<My>()) {

        if (other.physical.targetters.Contains (my))
            other.physical.targetters.Remove (my);
    }

    target.physical.targetters.Add (my);
    target.physical.targetted = true;
}
```

Here is my Grammar class that everything inherits from so they can access the global The class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Grammar : MonoBehaviour {

    public A a;
    public The the;
}
```

Here is my The (global utility) class

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class The : MonoBehaviour {

    public Grid grid;
    public GameObject world;

    public Player player;

    public GameObject squareParent;
    public GameObject linkParent;
    public GameObject nodeParent;
    public GameObject agents;

    public Vector2 HeadingFrom(float angle) { return new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad)); }
    public float AngleFrom(Vector2 heading) { return Mathf.Atan2 (heading.y, heading.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg; }
    public Vector2 RelativeHeadingFrom(Vector2 heading, float rotation) { return (Vector2)(HeadingFrom(AngleFrom(heading) - rotation)); }
    public float Distance(Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return (Heading(from,to)).magnitude; }
    public Vector2 Heading (Vector2 from, Vector2 to) { return to - from; }
    public Vector2 MidPoint (GameObject my, GameObject their) { return (my.transform.position + their.transform.position) / 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are detecting the clicks in your agent class is a bit off. While the property `Input.mousePosition` returns a Vector3 the Z component is always zero. The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) for the `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` function notes that the Z component of the supplied vector is the distance in world-units from the camera, this means that the world-position of your "clicks" in the Agent class will always be right next to the camera.

The usual approach is to either define the methods OnMouseDown() and OnMouseUp() (in your Agent class) or use `Camera.ScreenPointToRay`to create a Ray which is then used to do a raycast into the scene and then using the ray hit-result as the 'actual world' position of the mouse pointer. See this [answer](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/599097/need-help-understanding-screentoworldpoint.html) on *Unity Answers* for more about that.

I suggest you use the new event system (which is part of the new Unity GUI system) to detect if an agent has been clicked instead as this also handles touch input in case you want to your game to work on a mobile device.

What you would need to do to do that is:

- Implement the interface [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.OnPointerUp.html) and [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) in your agent class and handle the clicks in the methods the interfaces require you to define.
- Make sure you have some kind of collider (or trigger) on your agent.
- Make sure you add a [PhysicsRaycaster](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-PhysicsRaycaster.html) component on your Camera object.

You might also be interested in these interfaces:

- [IBeginDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.html)
- [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html)
- [IEndDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEndDragHandler.html)
- [IDropHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDropHandler.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the raycasting, but my project is 2D so I'm getting a load of errors, and can't quite work out how to do it using the RayCast2D.

I've also tried the OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown functions, but OnMouseUp seems to only reference the object from OnMouseDown. Obviously I'm never wanting to target the targeting agent, so that doesn't work. Is there no way to have an OnMouseUp function that doesn't care about what object the mouse button was pressed on?

Comment: I've solved the issue using a foreach loop within OnMouseUp, but it doesn't seem very elegant. Still interested if there is another way to do it without the additional loop.

Comment: I would suggest you try using the interfaces I described above, specifically the drag interfaces because those do and behave pretty much what you described and receive the "mouse up" event when you stop "dragging".